# strange lines in visual studio 2012 after activation

Tags: windows, visual-studio, visual-studio-2012

I have installed VS 2012 some days ago.After activation there are some strange lines in the UI
that appear on menu and code editor area.I don't know how to get rid of them.

http://mojoimage.com/free-image-hosting-11/4739vs2012.png

another example while repairing VS : [Picture](http://mojoimage.com/free-image-hosting-view-11.php?id=5943vs2012-updated.png)

Comment: Did you try to turn it off and on again?

Comment: Please add an image showing those strange lines

Answer (score 0):

VS2010 and 2012 use WPF for their UIs - it's likely this issue is with your graphics card or driver. Please ensure you're running the latest graphics driver versions. If the issue continues then I suggest you try running other WPF applications and seeing if they render things okay.

Comment: my graphic driver is the latest and its model is ATI X1550.this gpu runs modern warfare 2 smoothly.I hadn't this problem with VS until I activated it.